# Excel VBA code to generate graph form Date column and values in next column?

Tags: excel, graph, formatting

I am trying to create code to make a graph that is dependent upon date values in first column. So I have Column A which is the beginning of the week date, i.e. 1/1/17. In Column B I have the count from that week of issues occurred. I need Weekly graph of issues.
Eventually, I would like to similarly do this on a quarterly basis as well, but any help with the monthly issue first would be greatly appreciated. Here is a screenshot of the data which is located in Worksheets("Report").

[image: input for graph]

Answer (score 0):

**In this code you can create a Chart from a vba code, but you will have to change the source for the name of your worksheet, and I think that's it what you're looking for.
Change also the title.**

Sub Charts_Example1()

Dim MyChart As Chart   Dim position As Range   Set position = Sheets("Report").Range("A1")   Set MyChart = Charts.Add

With MyChart   .SetSourceData Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B13")   .ChartType = xlColumnClustered   End With   MyChart.Chart.HasTitle = True   MyChart.Chart.ChartTitle = " "

End Sub